Problem with create a .exe with cx_Freeze
I made an application where it uses several libraries and I wanted to create an executable of them, but when I use cx_Freeze it creates the executable but when I try to run it it generates this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\malva\anaconda3\envs\FMD\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 124, in run
    module_init.run(name + "__main__")
  File "C:\Users\malva\anaconda3\envs\FMD\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\console.py", line 17, in run
    exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
  File "interface.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\malva\anaconda3\envs\FMD\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from geopandas.io.file import _read_file as read_file  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\malva\anaconda3\envs\FMD\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 7, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "C:\Users\malva\anaconda3\envs\FMD\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    from fiona._env import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _env: The specified module could not be found.

I would like to know what could be happening, all the dependencies are installed correctly, I created an environment in conda just to install the dependencies correctly.
